# Git pull contents without affecting the local file changes and vice versa

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I am trying to fetch the file 'README' from my github repository to my ubuntu local.

The content of the file 'README' from Github repository is something like:

```
This is a git repo modified from github
```

Now for the same file i made changes in my local like:

```
This is a git repo locally modified from github local
```

Now in my

Ubuntu terminal, need to know how to get the file contents from Github without affecting my local contents and vice versa

**Scenario1 :** If I make changes locally for README file and say 'git status' i get

```
             modified:   README
```

in my terminal.

Here i need to add my local contents to github without affecting the contents.

**Scenario 2:** Any updates done to github, i need to get the update without affecting my local contents.

**Scenario 3:**  How to revert the changes done in my local and push the same in github to its original state.

Need the commands in all the scenarios.

UPDATED:

Tried the below:

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

I get as:

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
This is a git repo modified from github repo
=======
This is a git repo locally modified from github
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

How to get the updates from github and keep our local changes, without manually editing them

Comment: Did you try to use a `git stash` to store your local modifications? after that you run `git pull` to get all updates and then you run a `git stash pop` to recover your modified README

Comment: have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1: you want to add your local contents to the server without changing the state on the server??? `git branch` could be a solution to your problem. Or what contents should not be affected? [git branch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Scenario 2: `git fetch` downloads the changes from the server but does not apply them the to you local. `git pull` will apply them. [git fetch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Scenario 3: ich you revert your local changes, there is nothing left to push since you are already on a clean state?

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:** Learn Git, then commit your changes, then push your changes.

**Scenario 2:** You know that Git is a distributed VCS? You make changes locally, you commit the changes, you make more changes, you commit them, you possibly work on multiple branches locally and so on. When you want to integrate upstream changes, you `git fetch` those changes which pulls them down into the remote tracking branches, not affecting your local branches. Then you either `git merge` or `git rebase` the changes from the remote tracking branch into your local branch, depending on situation ('rebase' creates a linear histore with your commits on top of the changes coming in from remote, but should not be done for changes that are already pushed as it rewrites the history, 'merge' creates a merge commit to merge your changes and the remote changes). If you merge or rebase and have conflicts because you modified a file locally and there are changes coming in from remote, Git tells you so and expects you to resolve the conflict either manually or with a merge tool (`git mergetool`). `fetch+merge` or `fetch+rebase` can also be done with one command, namely `git pull` which either does a merge or rebase, depending on your configuration options and commandline parameters. This is handy if you do not want to review the remote changes before bringing the changes together with your local changes.

If you do not want to commit your modifications first, you can use `git stash` which saves and reverts your local uncommitted changes, then merge or rebase the remote changes into your local branch and then use `git stash pop` to get the changes applied again. If there were conflicts, `git stash pop` worked like `git stash apply`. You can then resolve the conflicts and if you are satisfied drop the top-most stash with `git stash drop`.

When merging or rebasing you can also use a merge strategy that completely uses your files, ignoring what comes in from remote (not only conflicting files). If you only want to use your versions of conflicting files, resolve the conflict for that file manually with `git checkout --ours -- your-file.ext`.

**Scenario 3:** If you did not commit or add to index locally, just do `git checkout .` in the root of the repo to revert all your local changes. If you already did commits you can use `git branch -f master origin/master` or `git reset --hard origin/master` to bring your local master branch to the remote branches state discarding all local commits.